# Installing mmvec

Tags: python, installation

I want to install your mmvec on my desktop computer from this link:
https://github.com/biocore/mmvec

But when I try "pip install mmvec", it shows the following error message:

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-MChPLG/biom-format/

I also tried "conda install mmvec -c conda-forge", but it also shows the following error:

conda: command not found

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you installed Conda? Try `conda --v`

Comment: _conda: command not found_ Do some research, you can find plenty of information on that.

Comment: Please share the **entire** error message(s) and traceback(s).

Comment: Thank you so much. After installing Conda it is fixed and I could run an example.